# Output of the webdriver program is not coming in the right format(tabular way)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WebTable_Dynamic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp");
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='reference notranslate']"));
        List<WebElement> rows=element.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
        for(int rowNum=1;rowNum<rows.size();rowNum++){
            List<WebElement> cells=rows.get(rowNum).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            for(int colNum=0;colNum<cells.size();colNum++){
                System.out.print(cells.get(colNum).getText());
                System.out.print("----");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

My program is extracting the elements from a table. 
Currently I am not getting the output in a tabular way due to line break `<br>` tags in the cell content. Can someone guide me in getting the o/p in a tabular way?

Comment: replace the `<br>` text with empty string/white space once you have the cell value from `getText()`. If you want to preserve the line breaks in your output, you will need much more formatting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply....I tried using this: String cellValue=cells.get(colNum).getText().replaceAll("<br>", " ");
System.out.print(cellValue); .....But in vain :(

Comment: What is  the output from `getText()`? Does it have any newline characters such as `\r`  or `\n`?